# Having trouble linking C++ to Fortran using ICL/IFORT

Tags: c++, linker-errors, intel-fortran

So I'm following the example from
http://difdop.polytechnique.fr/wiki/index.php/How_to_Bessel_Functions_in_C

Except I'm trying to use the intel compilers ICL and IFORT instead of gcc and g77.

The code I have in C++ is:

```
extern "C" void zbesj_(double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double*, double*, int*, int*);
typedef std::complex<double> CplxDbl;

CplxDbl besselj(double nu, CplxDbl z)
{
    int kode=1;
    int n=1;
    double zr=z.real();
    double zi=z.imag();
    int nz,ierr;
    double cyr[1],cyi[1];
    CplxDbl res;

    zbesj_(&zr,&zi,&nu,&kode,&n,cyr,cyi,&nz,&ierr);
    if(ierr!=0){
        printf("error!\n");
    }

    return CplxDbl(cyr[0],cyi[0]);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CplxDbl J0=besselj(0.0,CplxDbl(0.1,0.2));
        printf("\nJ0(0.1+0.2i)= %.17f  %+.17f I\n",J0.real(),J0.imag());

        return 0;
}
```

Additionally, I have zbesj.f and all its dependencies. I've tried calling ICL first, then IFORT and vice versa. Doesn't compile :(

```
icl -c CallFortranFromC.cpp
ifort -o test CallFortranFromC.obj *.f
```

Always end up with the same linker error:

```
CallFortranFromC.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zbesj_ referenced in function main 
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch on symbol names in the link stage. If you do:

```
dumpbin  /SYMBOLS zbesj.obj
```

you'll see symbol name in object file is UPPER CASE and has no trailing UNDERSCORE.

Easiest fix is this (assuming you don't want to change your C code):

```
icl -c CallFortranFromC.cpp
ifort  /names:lowercase /assume:underscore  -o test CallFortranFromC.obj *.f
```